# SDL_GetKeyState not detecting japanese keypresses

Tags: sdl

SDL_GetKeyState isn't detecting the keypress state of various keys on several Japanese keyboards that I've tested. Specifically Y| (next to backspace) and \_ (next to right shift) and the Kana composition keys on each side of the SPACE bar. Y| and \_ generate and return characters, but their keypress state is not noticed.

Trimmed down code. Pressing the keys return characters:

```
if (SDL_PollEvent(&ev))
  switch(ev.type) {
    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
      ch = ev.key.keysym.unicode;
      // Y| and \_ return characters
```

But detecting their state does not work. Using code similar to this shows no response to pressing the keys:

```
SDL_PumpEvents();
keystate = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);
while(SDL_PollEvent(&ev))
  { if (ev.type == SDL_QUIT) exit(0); }
for (arg=0; arg<512; arg++)
  { printf("%2x ",keystate[arg]); }
```

Is there a "deeper" level I can call to detect keypress states? Or is SDL immovably bound to only those keyboards that the authors have ever encountered?

Comment: Did you enable Unicode via `SDL_EnableUNICODE()`?  Can you repro in SDL2?

Comment: In event, what is the value of `ev.key.keysym.sym`? SDL 1.2 `SDLK_LAST == 323`, not 512, so you're walking on some risky grounds here reading till 512 and ignoring numkeys. SDL2 have 512 range, that will probably be ok for you.

Comment: Yeah, it was just some thrown-together test code.
SDL_EnableUNICODE(1) doesn't make any difference.
As a thought I tried classic test=GetAsyncKeyState(0xE2) (0xE2=righthand '\' key), but that just caused the exec to bomb out with Address out of range.